# Function that will take an index of an image and return its color

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to write a function that will take an image as input and then return a function that will take an index and return the color of that index. This is what I got so far:

```
def generator(image):
    def index2color(index1): 
        return image[index1]
    return index2color
```

Lets try it:

```
 generator2 = generator("flower.jpg")
 print (generator2((3)))

 >>> w
```

So this will return the index in the string but not the index for the picture. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just operate on the image. Google it otherwise, there are great tutorials on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the image in to an appropriate object first, then operate on the image object. Like this:

```
flower_img = cv2.imread('flower.jpg')
generator2 = generator(flower_img)
```

Consider working through this for a better understanding of what you can do: https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/df2/tutorial_py_basic_ops.html

Comment: Thanks! That was the part i was missing.